# GRUB shows apurple screen when trying to boot windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

SO guys. Recently I'm having a weird problem. I had my windows 10 and Ubuntu set up in dual boot for nearly one month. Two days ago for some reason, I clean installed windows and as expected, I couldn't boot into Ubuntu. So, I followed the official boot-repair documentation and everything worked just fine. But yesterday, I clean installed windows again and performed the boot repair, restarted my pc and GRUB opened. Then I chose windows 10 and I was greeted with just a purple screen and nothing else. I chose 'repair your computer ' from the Windows installation disk. and ran ' bootrec.exe /fixmbr'. Then I was able to boot into windows but no GRUB as expected. I repeated the process again and again but no luck. Please help me. Also if it helps, my windows is 64 bit and Ubuntu is 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you disable **fast startup** in Windows?

If you didn't do that:

1. Go to **Control panel -> All control panel items -> Power options -> Choose what the powers button do**
2. Click on **Change settings that are currently unavailable**
3. Uncheck **Turn on fast startup**
4. Uncheck **Hibernate**
5. Restart entering Bios/UEFI
6. Move Ubuntu on top of Windows
7. Save and restart

I had the same issue just two days ago and this worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it!